# Why are N//x and math.floor providing different outputs to calculate the sum the digits of fact(100)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used this to find the sum of all the digits of fact(100) and it gave me the correct output which is 648.

```
while(fact>0):
    r=fact%10
    sum=sum+r
    fact=fact//10

print(sum)
```

But, on using the same script with the // replaced by the math.floor() function, I obtained 675 as the output.

```
while(fact>0):
    r=fact%10
    sum=sum+r
    fact=floor(fact/10)

print(sum)
```

Please help me wrap my head around this anomaly. From what I've learnt N//x and math.floor() are interchangeable.

Comment: How about you print your values at each step and narrow down exactly what the calculation is that produces a different result?

Comment: Float arithmetic error is larger than one with very large numbers, you must use integer division which is always exact for that reason.

Comment: When you use `floor(fact/10)` you're converting `fact/10` to floating point, which doesn't have enough precision for numbers with more than 17 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Using `/` outputs a float which opens the door to [float arithmetic error](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). In short it means the unit digit of your division is wrong due to how computers store real numbers and that you should not rely on float division.

### Details

Squeezing infinitely many real number in a finite number of binary representations is impossible. For that reason, each real number can only be approximated by a float number with a certain error. This is well-known and even though it is not specific to Python, it's documentation [mentions it](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

It is possible to compute the maximum floating-point error of an approximation, although just know that for very big floats such as `fact(100) / 10`, the error is bigger than one. This means rounding to an integer gives an incorrect result.

For this reason whenever you can use integer arithmetic instead of float arithmetic you should since integer arithmetic is always exact.